# Getting current passed business dates and total business days from custom calendar

Tags: python, pandas, date, calendar

I have a pandas CustomBusinessDay calendar defined as below:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar

class feriados(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, year=2022),
        Holiday('May Day', month=5, day=1, year=2022),
        Holiday('14/04', month=4, day=17, year=2022),
        Holiday('Constitution Day', month=4, day=21, year=2022),
        Holiday('Pentecost Sunday', month=5, day=1, year=2022),
        Holiday('Corpus Christi', month=9, day=7, year=2022),
        Holiday('Assumption of the Blessed Virgin Mary', month=10, day=12, year=2022),
        Holiday('All Saints Day', month=11, day=2,  year=2022),
        Holiday('Independence Day', month=11, day=15, year=2022),
        Holiday('Christmas Day', month=12, day=25, year=2022),
        
        
        Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, year=2023),
        Holiday('Carnival', month=2, day=20, year=2023),
        Holiday('Carnival', month=2, day=21, year=2023),
        Holiday('Passion of Christ', month=4, day=7, year=2023),
        Holiday('TakeTooths', month=4, day=21, year=2023),
        Holiday('Labour Day', month=5, day=1, year=2023),
        Holiday('Corpus Christi', month=6, day=8, year=2023),
        Holiday('Independence Day', month=9, day=7, year=2023),
        Holiday('Nossa Sr.a Aparecida - Padroeira do Brasil', month=10, day=12, year=2023),
        Holiday('Finados', month=11, day=2, year=2023),
        Holiday('Proclamação da República', month=11, day=15, year=2023),
        Holiday('Christmas Day', month=12, day=25, year=2023),]


BUSINESS_DAY = CustomBusinessDay(
    calendar=feriados(),
    weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri')
```

I want to calculate how many business days have already passed and how many total business days we have in the current month.

Can anybody help me with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `BUSINESS_DAY`, you can use [`pd.bdate_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html) to get what you expect:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin, MonthEnd

today = pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
bdays = pd.bdate_range(today - MonthBegin(), today + MonthEnd(), freq='C',
                       weekmask=BUSINESS_DAY.weekmask, 
                       holidays=BUSINESS_DAY.holidays)
```

Output:

```
>>> bdays
DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04',
               '2023-08-07', '2023-08-08', '2023-08-09', '2023-08-10',
               '2023-08-11', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-16',
               '2023-08-17', '2023-08-18', '2023-08-21', '2023-08-22',
               '2023-08-23', '2023-08-24', '2023-08-25', '2023-08-28',
               '2023-08-29', '2023-08-30', '2023-08-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')

# 9 business days are passed
>>> (bdays == today).argmax()
9

# 23 business days in the current month
>>> len(bdays)
23
```

Comment: Hey, I'm having a little problem with this code today (the first business day of the month), len(bdays) keeps returning 43 days. What would be a solution for this?

Comment: @JoãoWeckerle. Replace `today - MonthBegin()` with `today - MonthBegin(today.day != 1)`. `MonthBegin` will be `MonthBegin(0)` if day is 1 else `MonthBegin(1)`.